# Haproxy disable Secure Renegotiation

Tags: security, ssl, https, haproxy, tls

I want to disable secure renegotiation in HAproxy-1.5.2, but can not find anything about it on the official documentation: http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt

My SSL HAproxy conf:

```
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:...

bind :443 ssl crt ./cert.pem no-sslv3
```

Actually:

```
root# openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:443 |grep "Secure"
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```

I want:

```
root# openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:443 |grep "Secure"
Secure Renegotiation NOT supported
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Renegotiation is a security issue because it is a via for MITM attacks.
Secure Renegotiation solves this problem but increases probability of success of the DDOS attacks. I want disable renegotiation (all, secure and not secure). It is possible?

Comment: The DoS attack only works if client-initiated renegotiation is supported, which it should not be on any secure platform. Server-initiated renegotiation is safe and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @MichaelHampton. With this the issue is solved.